# Como hacer para retonar un valor de esta funcion en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

esta funcion me devuelve undefined, he intentado de varias maneras pero nada, me funciona bien si la hago una por una pero lo que quiero es ahorrar codigo y no hacer una por cada mes

```js
   function buscador(mes,year){


  var url="../controlador/funciones.php";
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {"totalingresosbuscado":'elcodigo','buscado':mes,'tabla':'ingresos','campo':'mes','year':year},
 success: function(data)
          {
      return data;
       
    }
  });
  
}

var enero = buscador(Mayo,2019);

console.log(enero);
```

Answer (score 1):

No estás devolviendo nada en la función. La que está devolviendo es la llamada Ajax. Necesitarías otro `return` para la función, debajo de la llamada de Ajax.

El problema es que Ajax es una llamada asíncrona. Entonces tendrías que esperar a que la llamada Ajax haya terminado, que no sabes cuándo es, tendrías que usar [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

Otra opción es procesar el resultado en la opción `success` de Ajax:

```js
function buscador (mes, year) {
    var url="../controlador/funciones.php";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {"totalingresosbuscado":'elcodigo','buscado':mes,'tabla':'ingresos','campo':'mes','year':year},
        success: function (data) {
            // Procesar lo que quieras o lo que necesites aquí.
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

buscador('Mayo', 2019);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```